# What was the first team sport ever invented?

Tags: history

What was the first team sport ever invented?

By team sport I mean:

- group of two or more players playing against another group of two or more players
- athletic competition involving an agreed upon set of rules and objectives

Comment: war doesn't count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Team sport: "Most likely Tsu Chu , which was played in China as early as 3000 BC" - It was similar to soccer.

[First sport ever invented](https://www.reference.com/history/first-sport-ever-invented-74e7e8206887977c)

Answer (score 2):

The Mesoamerican ballgame and its descendants have been played since 1400BCE.

While they may not count directly as team sports, these may also have been competed in by teams:

Ancient Egyptian records indicate organised competition in such things as swimming, wrestling and javelin.

Ancient Chinese records indicate organised competition in gymnastics.

Ancient Persian records indicate organised competition in wrestling and jousting.

*Sources to follow*